# writing to global variables in using doSNOW and doing parallelization in R?

Tags: r, foreach

Is there a problem when accessing/writing to global variable in using doSNOW package on multiple cores?

In the below program, each of the MyCalculations(ii) writes to the ii-th column of the matrix "globalVariable"...

Do you think the result will be correct? Will there be hidden catches?

Thanks a lot!

p.s. I have to write out to the global variable because this is a simplied example, in fact I have lots of outputs that need to be transported from within the parallel loops... therefore, probably the only way is to write out to global variables...

```
library(doSNOW)
MaxSearchSpace=44*5
globalVariable=matrix(0, 10000, MaxSearchSpace)
cl<-makeCluster(7)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
foreach (ii = 2:nMaxSearchSpace, .combine=cbind, .verbose=F) %dopar%
  {
   MyCalculations(ii)
  }

stopCluster(cl)
```

p.s. I am asking - within the DoSnow framework, is there any danger of accessing/writing global variables... thx

Comment: You might consider using [doRedis](https://github.com/bwlewis/doRedis) which would handle your issue with the need for accessing global variables.

Answer (score 9):

Since this question is a couple months old, I hope you've found an answer by now. However, in case you're still interested in feedback, here's something to consider:

When using `foreach` with a parallel backend, you won't be able to assign to variables in R's global environment in the way you're attempting (you probably noticed this). Using a *sequential* backend, assignment will work, but not using a *parallel* one like with `doSNOW`.

Instead, save all the results of your calculations for each iteration in a list and return this to an object, so that you can extract the appropriate results after all calculations have been completed.

My suggestion starts similarly to your example:

```
library(doSNOW)
MaxSearchSpace <- 44*5
cl <- makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())

# do not create the globalVariable object

registerDoSNOW(cl)

# Save the results of the `foreach` iterations as 
# lists of lists in an object (`theRes`)

theRes <- foreach (ii = 2:MaxSearchSpace, .verbose=F) %dopar%
  {
# do some calculations
   theNorms <- rnorm(10000)
   thePois <- rpois(10000, 2)
# store the results in a list
   list(theNorms, thePois)
  }
```

After all iterations have been completed, extract the results from `theRes` and store them as objects (e.g., `globalVariable`, `globalVariable2`, etc.)

```
globalVariable1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(theRes, "[[", 1))
globalVariable2 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(theRes, "[[", 2))
```

With this in mind, if you are performing calculations with each iteration that are dependent on the results of calculations from previous iterations, then this type of parallel computing is not the approach to take.

Comment: Is there still no way to write to a global variable from a foreach loop? A list wont work for me since I am using the foreach loop to assign an element from one array to another. ex ```list1[i]=list2[i-4]```

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov is it possible to assign after completing the calculations? Or are the calculations dependent upon one another?

Comment: the calculations aren't dependent on each other. The issue is that I cant assign program I am using doesn't allow for lists to be assigned the variable all at once, and it needs to be done one at a time.

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov, I'm not sure that I fully understand the constraints of the program you're using. It seems to me that your situation warrants a new question.